# Cant add images to pygame

Tags: python, pygame-surface

I tried making a simple game, but every time I try to run the code I get an error in the images location. Python can't find it. I tried putting the images in the desktop, or even using `"import os"`, but neither work.

How can I make Python identify the correct filepath and run the following code:

```py
walkRight = [pygame.image.load(os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\Game\\R1")),
pygame.image.load(os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\Game\\R2")), 
pygame.image.load(os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\Game\\R3")),
pygame.image.load(os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Anas\\Desktop\\Game\\R4"))]
```

Comment: What's with the `chdir` command?  Please refer to the documentation and see what it returns -- you *cannot* `load` the result of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `os.chdir` in this case. It changes the current working directory to the given path. You can use [`os.path.normpath`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.normpath) to normalize the path. You can also check for debug purposes if the file actually exists with [`os.path.isfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile).